# The expected value of a probability mass function, and hospital payments...

Tags: probability

Let the random variable X be the number of days that a certain patient needs to be in the hospital. Suppose X has the pmf:

$ f(x) = (5-x) / 10$ where x = 1, 2, 3, 4

If the patient is to receive 200 from an insurance company for each of the first two days in the hospital and 100 for each day after the first two days, what is the expected payment for hospitalization?

So first off, the way I did this was exactly by the book where I did:

$E(x)= \sum_{x=1}^4 f(x)\cdot x$
using this reveals that E(x) = 2 which should mean that the expected payment should be 400 since he stays in the hospital for 2 days, but the actual answer is 360. Why is that? What did i do wrong?

Comment: You need to distinguish between the average of a function and function of the average. Assuming that your $E[X]$ calculation is correct, you computed the expected payment as $2\times 200$.  What you are asked to find is $E[g(X)]$ where $g(\cdot)$ is a _function_ that takes on value $200, 400, 500, 600$ according as $X=1,2,3,4$.  In general, $E[g(X)]$ is **not** the same as $g(E[X])$. Find $200\times 0.4+400\times 0.3+500\times 0.2+600\times 0.1$ to get $360$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in that you cannot get the expectation of the random variable of payouts by taking the expected value of hospital stays and evaluating it for a payout.

Also note that the expectation of a random variable should be a number, not a function.

Try looking at this:

$E(X) = .4 * 200 + .3 * 400 + .2 * 500 + .1 * 600 = 360$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\operatorname{Pay}(x) =\begin{cases} 200x & 1\leq x \leq 2 \\ 400+100(x-2) & 3\leq x \leq 4\end{cases}$

You're trying to find: $\operatorname{Pay}(\operatorname{E}[X]) = \operatorname{Pay}\left(\sum\limits_{x=1}^4 x f(x)\right)$

However, you require: $\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Pay}(X)] = \sum\limits_{x=1}^4 \operatorname{Pay}(x) f(x)$

That's not the same thing at all.